# Bootstrap 4 Dashboard Example Responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

Today I was looking for a dashboard theme, and I found the dashboard example on bootstrap site (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/examples/dashboard/). I liked it so much, but there's 2 things that I don't know how to work on.

In a small screen (mobile, for example) the sidebar simply hide and there's no way to show it or collapse it from the navbar. Any of you have ever worked with this example? I really liked that but I can't use it without this things.

I tried some code from other answers here in StackOverFlow but nothing worked.

Comment: Hi! found out 'display: block!important;' is missing when media width is 765px and lower.

Comment: Dear You need to customize that a little bit by yourself the class`d-none` on this line `<nav class="bg-light col-md-2 d-md-block d-none sidebar">` hide it on mobile view you need to remove that and style it yourself. Generallay its not hte way to hide nav on mobile most dashboard make that visible on toggle IDK why he hides that. You can use some other dashboard themes which were free online and way much better then then that like  https://www.bootstrapdash.com/bootstrap-4-admin-templates/

Comment: Hi @Awais I'm really interested in this specific theme because it's simple and easy to work on. My problem is the fixed navbar without a collapse option. I figured out the `d-none`. Anyway, I really don't know how to put it to work, I'm thinking in pay to someone to do it for me.

Comment: @NetoMello Dear You cant set nav bar without collapse as all admin panel do else you dont have space for your main content to display for user and it look bad. Second you will do it by yourself just need see the toggle navigation examples either in themes or somewhere else you will find the solution